# ASP.NET Rate Limit API with Queue Limit with partition key

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, rate-limiting

I am using the below code,

```
            services.AddRateLimiter(rateLimiterOptions =>
            {
                rateLimiterOptions.RejectionStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status429TooManyRequests;

                rateLimiterOptions.AddPolicy(GexRateLimitingPolicies.Concurrent,
                    httpContext => RateLimitPartition.GetConcurrencyLimiter(
                        partitionKey: httpContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? httpContext.Request.GetIpAddress(),
                        factory: _ => new ConcurrencyLimiterOptions
                        {
                            PermitLimit = 1,
                            QueueLimit = 0,
                        }
                    ));
            });


..........................................
            app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseRateLimiter();
    

................................................


        [Authorize]
        [EnableRateLimiting(GexRateLimitingPolicies.Concurrent)]
        public IActionResult MyApi()
        {
```

I want if same user call `MyApi` 2 times, he should get 429 error. But different users are allowed to call this method concurrently.

When I run the app, if different users call the same `MyApi` at same time then one of them will get 429 error.

Update: After changing the order of middlewares,

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRateLimiter();
```

Both user get different partition key but there is no rejection. All requests are blocked/queued.

Also, if I put a breakpoint at,

```
RateLimitPartition.GetConcurrencyLimiter(
                        partitionKey: httpContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? httpContext.Request.GetIpAddress(),
                        factory: _ => new ConcurrencyLimiterOptions
```

It only hit for the second request when first request finish (for the same user).

I used Network tool to monitor and found that browser is queuing the request and send one after the other.

Comment: Are you confident that `httpContext.User.Identity?.Name` is not `null`? Could it be in which case your policy would be using `httpContext.Request.GetIpAddress()`.

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre]? Also where `app.UseAuthorization()` call is placed?

Comment: The rate limiting is working fine without Queue Limit. The issue is that QueuLimit is impacting all users. The code I showed you is you can copy and reproduce in. NET 8

Comment: Hi Imran, please check how long the GetIpAddress method takes? Maybe we can use ` partitionKey: httpContext.User.Identity?.Name ?? "anonymous", ` for testing.

Comment: Hi Jason, actually both are done from logged-in user

Comment: @Peppermintology you are right. The issue was with ordering of UseAuthentication/UseAuthorization/UseRateLimiter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the ordering of middleware,

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseRateLimiter();
```

Make sure try on different browsers and Network tools instead of rely on Edge/Chrome as they queue/serilaize the requests.